# MultipartFormDataStreamProvider.FormData.AllKeys return empty key name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Here's my client code which adds a `StringContent` in a `MultipartFormDataContent` object.

```
using (MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
       // other codes here 

       ResponseMessage testMesage = new ResponseMessage() { PublicId = "Hello World",
                                                            Url = "http://localhost:55000/" };
       StringContent jsonPart = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testMesage));
       jsonPart.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
       jsonPart.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
       form.Add(jsonPart, "JsonContentName", "JsonContentFileName");

       // other codes here 
}
```

Now, when I debugged the code inside the receiving controller, I was expecting to have a `Key` name to either  *JsonContentName* or *JsonContentFileName* but it turns out to be empty

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
foreach (string key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
{
     foreach (string val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
     {
           string _key = key; // expecting JsonContentName  or JsonContentFileName
           string _val = val;
     }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH0nz.jpg)

So my question is, how can I add `Key` name to every content that I add inside `MultipartFormDataContent`?

Comment: How did you solve this?